# Why mi property do not save the value when I use SudzC?

Tags: ios, web-services, tableview, sudzc

I am using SudzC to get webservices, that webservice give me data, I tried to save the data in a property, but when I use to fill a tableview the property don't have any data. I use the debugger to view the property.

This es my handler

```
- (void) ConsultarUnidadesOrganizacionalesPorEmpresaHandler: (id) value {

// Handle errors
if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
    return;
}

// Handle faults
if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", value);
    return;
}               


// Do something with the NSMutableArray* result
NSMutableArray *result = (NSMutableArray*)value;
NSMutableArray *unidadOrganizacional = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.myData = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < [result count]; i++)
{
    EWSUnidadNegocio *empresa = [[EWSUnidadNegocio alloc] init];
    empresa = [result objectAtIndex:i];
    [unidadOrganizacional addObject:[empresa Descripcion]];

}

self.myData = unidadOrganizacional;
```

}

And this is the part where I use the web service

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

EWSEmpresaWebServiceSvc *service = [[EWSEmpresaWebServiceSvc alloc]init];


[service ConsultarUnidadesOrganizacionalesPorEmpresa:self action:@selector(ConsultarUnidadesOrganizacionalesPorEmpresaHandler:) EmpresaId:self.empresaID];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

And the tableview is empty. Why does this happen? How can I use the data and fill my tableview?

Comment: do you retain your property? one more thing just to test, after self.myData = unidadOrganizacional; try in a loop to print all the content of your array just to be sure that it contains something.

Comment: Yes, my property is retain. And I use NSLog and the data is displayed in the screen with the data that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I just have to put

```
[_myTableView reloadData]
```

at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code this way :

```
self.myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
// your loop 
[sel setMyData:unidadOrganizacional];
```

Comment: weird, what about your tableView dataSource? numberOfSectionInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection? because if mydata is not empty and are you able to see it's content from the controller in wich you manage your tableView the problem could be in your dataSources methods

Answer (score 0):

try loading it in a dictionary:

```
dict = [resp objectForKey:@"YourKey"]; 
  if( ( dict == nil ) || ![dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ) { 
NSLog( @"WARNING: %@", [dict description]); 
  return; 
} 

 empID = [[dict objectForKey:@"empresaID"]copy];

 NSLog(@"Your Value: %@", empID);
```